# Show that $\int_0^{\frac{π}{2}}(1+\sin^2 x)\,dx <\frac{3π}{4}$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

Show that :

$\int_0^{\frac{π}{2}}(1+\sin^2 x)dx <\frac{3π}{4}$

Without calculus integral of

$\int_0^{\frac{π}{2}}\sin^2x\,dx$

Can $\sin x≤x$ or $\sin x≤\tan x\:$ work here !!

Comment: It's so easy to compute the integral!

Answer (score 1):

$sin^2(x)={{1-cos(2x)}\over 2}$ implies that $1+sin^2(x)={3\over 2}-{{cos(2x)}\over 2}$

$\int_0^{{\pi\over 2}}{{cos(2x)}\over 2}dx=0$ and $\int_0^{\pi\over 2}{3\over 2}dx={{3\pi}\over 4}$

Answer (score 0):

=The integral can be split into two parts, $\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}1dx=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\sin^2xdx$.  We know $\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$ and $\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\cos^2x\,dx=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\sin^2x\,dx$  Therefore $\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\sin^2x\,dx=\frac{\pi}{4}$.  As a result $\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}1+\sin^2x\,dx=\frac{3\pi}{4}$, not $\lt$ as proposed.

Comment: @Rozeflowers. The question you ask in comments is very interesting. Why don't you post it ?

Comment: @Roze flowers  I believe I have a solution, but it is much more extensive than a comment.  Post it as another question.